# Adding username without hardcoding, chatbuilder application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First off I am openly a newbie (to this site and coding) so I apologize in advance if the answer to this question is overly easy, however I am desperately in need of some help.

I have developed "chatbuilder" as a part of my interview process to a development bootcamp. Unfortunately I hardcoded my username within the chatSend function which includes an ajax call. I want to use the prompt input for the username due to the fact that hypothetically this chat should have the ability to have many users, not just me and the robotchatters. I have spent far too much time trying to figure out the right way to do this, hours worth of trial and error while I realize the fix probably will take about 45 seconds. I am posting my full code, if someone could show me how implement this properly it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"> </script>
  </head>
    <body>
     <script>

     Chat.guide.start();



      delete Chat.display;
      delete Chat.fetch;
      delete Chat.send;


      function chatDisplay(str){
      $(".messages").append( "<li>" + str  + "</li>");
      };

      function chatFetch(fun){
        var obj = {};
        var result = [];
        $.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=-createdAt",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          async : false,
          complete : function(data)
           {
              obj = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
           }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.results.length; i++) {
          result.push(obj.results[i]);
        };
        result.sort(function(a,b){
          a = new Date(a.createdAt);
          b = new Date(b.createdAt);
          return a<b ? -1 : a>b ? 1 : 0;
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
          result[i] = result[i].text;
        }
        fun(result);
      };


      function chatSend(str){
      var user = document.URL.slice(document.URL.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
      var userpost =  $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          data: JSON.stringify({text: 'Daniel: ' + str,}),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          async : false,
        });
        return userpost;
      };


      function chatRefresh(){
        $(".messages").empty();
        function chatTether(arr){
          for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            chatDisplay(arr[i]);
          }
        };
        chatFetch(chatTether);
      };
      setInterval(chatRefresh,3000);


      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".send").on("click", function(){
          chatSend($(".draft").val())
          $(".draft").val('');
        });
      });

    </script>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Fixed Chat</h2>

    <input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send">send</button>

    <ul class="messages">
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I did get you in the right way:
first you make smth like this

```
var promptName = prompt('Enter your name', 'Some name just in case))');
```

and then you just add this to your ajax func:

```
 function chatSend(str){
  var user = document.URL.slice(document.URL.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
  var str = promptName + someElseStringYouWant;
  var userpost =  $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
      data: JSON.stringify({text: str,}),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      async : false,
    });
    return userpost;
  };
```

BTW: Declare the `promptName` variable in global scope, so your send message function can see it.
UPD: ok, forget 'bout the prompt stuff, I said before, cause it's built in to your lib, and I've found just minified version of it, so i can't find a variable, where it's stored, so you should try your previous method with url

```
 function chatSend(str){
  var url = $(location).attr('href');
  var user = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
  var fullString = user + ': ' + str;
  var userpost =  $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
      data: JSON.stringify({text: fullString,}),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      async : false,
    });
    return userpost;
  };
```

So, you get substring from your url and it's done.

P.S. you can accept the answer even if you can not upvote ;)

Comment: Just figured out how to accept the answer lol. Sorry like I said "newbie!"